# Finding the longest list in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I need to write a predicate longestList/2 such that longestList(L1,L2) is satisfied if L2 is the longest
nested list from the list of lists L1.

```
?- longestList([[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]],LI).
LI = [[1, 2, 3, 4]] ;
No
?- longestList([[a,b,c],[d,e],[f,g,h]],LI).
LI = [[f, g, h],[a,b,c]];
No
```

Could someone please help me with intuition to go about solving it?

Comment: you should name which features (read libraries) you are allowed to use...

Comment: we can use length and append. does that answers your question?

Comment: Sure. There are no constrains. As long as its easy to understand.

Comment: Actually, I would do this recursively and have two accumulators. One would be the current maximum length seen so far, and the other would be the current collection of lists that have that length. You need to give this a try on your own and show where you're specifically stuck.

Comment: Something i tried so far http://pastebin.com/KaM7a733

Comment: Please add attempted code to your question.

Comment: By the way, your description doesn't quite match your example. The description says, *`longestList(L1,L2)` is satisfied if `L2` is the longest nested list from the list of lists`L1`*, so it indicates that `L2` is one of the lists in `L1`, not a list of lists. In that case, the predicate may have one or more solutions, each produced through backtracking. Which is it to be?

Comment: First help: `lists_longestlists/2` is a much more relational name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

member/2 will allow you to peek an element (a list for your case) from a list: so, if you have a member_length/3 predicate, you could code

```
longestList(Lists, Longest) :-
  member_length(Lists, Longest, N),
  \+ ( member_length(Lists, _Another, M), M > N ).
```

then to find all longest, you can use findall/3...

Answer (score 3):

Here's an outline for a basic, recursive approach. Not quite as crisp as the answer @CapelliC gave, but on the same order of simplicity.

The idea is to traverse the list and keep track of the longest list you've seen so far, and what it's length is. Then you step through the list recursively and update these arguments for the recursion if the conditions indicate so. It's a slight elaboration on the technique used to do a recursive "max list element" predicate. To do this, you set up a call to include more arguments (the current longest list, and its length).

```
longestList([], []).
longestList([L|Ls], LongestList) :-
    length(L, Length),
    % Start with the first element (L) being my best choice so far
    longestList(Ls, L, Length, LongestList).
```

Here is the expanded predicate with the new arguments.

```
longestList([L|Ls], LongestListSoFar, GreatestLengthSoFar, LongestList) :-
    % Here, you need to examine L and determine if it should supersede
    %  the longest list so far and its length. You need to keep in mind that
    %  if the length of L is the same as the max length so far, then I
    %  may choose to keep the LongestListSoFar, or choose L. Both are
    %  valid solutions for this call. This is a good place to use the `;`
    %  operator, and to be cautious about parenthesizing expressions since
    %  the comma has higher precedence than the semi-colon.
    %  Also, you'll need to make a recursive call to longestList(Ls, ??, ??, LongestList).
    %  The arguments to the recursion will depend upon which way the decision flow goes.
    %
    % After all that to-do, don't let it scare you: it's about 5 lines of code :)
    %
longestList([], LongestListSoFar, ??, ??).
    % Fill in the ??. What should they be at list's end ([])?
    %   Do I even care now what the 3rd argument is?
```

Hopefully that's enough to give you something to think about to make progress. Or, use @CapelliC's solution and write the `member_length/3` predicate. :) Note that, as in his solution, the above solution would generate each maximum list on backtracking if there are more than one. So, you could use `findall/3` if you want to get all the solutions in one list.

Answer (score 1):

Following code, which uses if else, seem to work partially. It has to be called with 0 length and so one cannot get length itself from here.

```
longest_list([H|T], LongList, LongLen):-
    length(H, Len),
    (Len > LongLen -> 
        longest_list(T, [H], Len); 
        longest_list(T, LongList, LongLen)).

longest_list([],Finallist,_):-writeln(Finallist).

?- longest_list([[1,2,3], [3,4], [4,5,6,7,8], [5,3,4]], Longestlist, 0).
[[4,5,6,7,8]]
true.
```

However, the variable itself is not coming:

```
?- writeln(Longestlist).
_G1955
true.
```

It may give some ideas.